# Finding the average value in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, average

I have an `950000x1` array of values, for example `[1e15  2.5e12  ...etc]`. but when I do the following to get the average value, I get values as `NaN`.

```
avg=mean(g1)
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code runs fine on my machine (Core i7, 16GB RAM, Linux Mint v12, Matlab 2012b):

```
T = 1e9;
Vec = ones(T, 1) * 1e200;
M = mean(Vec);
```

This suggests to me your array of values contains an `NaN` somewhere. Note, even if your array contained numbers larger than double floating point can handle (ie on the order of 1e320 or thereabouts), then the `mean` function will return `Inf`, not `NaN`.

Try `any(isnan(Vec))` over your array. If it returns a `1`, then you'll know it contains an `NaN`. If it does, then the following code will remove the NaNs.

```
Vec(isnan(Vec)) = [];
```

If you think this has resolved your query, then feel free to click the tick mark next to my answer. Cheers!

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty Interesting. okay, next step, can you try running your code in debug mode. Specifically, try going line-by-line through the `mean` function (using f10 and f11 keys) and see where the NaN appears, then post the results in your question? You can initiate debug mode by setting a breakpoint in your code before the call to `mean`.

Comment: yes its returning a Nan, can you guide me on how to remove those values, i.e changing them to 0

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty I'll edit my answer to include code on how to remove NaNs.

Comment: I have another doubt, I am plotting a map between x,y and density. x and y are distances. Is there any method apart from scatterplot to plot it. I want the density to be shown in colorbar

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty This is a completely unrelated question. What is the point in answering it here in the comments where it won't turn up on standard site searches or Google searches? Remember, this is a resource for everyone, not just a place where people answer your questions. Further, if you write a question where all forum members can see it, then you'll likely get a better answer. I suggest you write it up as an entirely new question and include some code that indicates what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing `NaN`s before querying the `mean` function, you can just use `nanmean`, which ignores `NaN` values when calcuting the mean:

[nanmean](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/nanmean.html):

> y = nanmean(X) is the mean of X, computed after removing NaN values.

It also works on matrices, which does not work if you remove the `NaN`s.